# Java XPath Compile can't query tag with unique namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I got a tag with a unique namespace in it, just that tag alone. I introduced XML name space context but still my program is returning 0 nodes.

```
// Create DocumentBuilderFactory for reading xml file
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(text)));

        // Create XPathFactory for creating XPath Object
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        // Create XPath object from XPathFactory
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                if ("cam".equals(prefix))
                    return "urn:xxx:1.0:logging";
                else if ("soapenv".equals(prefix))
                    return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                else if ("xml".equals(prefix))
                    return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
                return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
            }

            // This method isn't necessary for XPath processing.
            public String getPrefix(String uri) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            // This method isn't necessary for XPath processing either.
            public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        });

        // Compile the XPath expression for getting the response
         XPathExpression xPathExpr =
         xpath.compile("/cam:message/cam:response/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/Info[1]/property[@name='response']/text()");
        

        // XPath text example : executing xpath expression in java
        // Object result = xPathExpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        // NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        // int length = nodes.getLength();

        String result1 = (String) xPathExpr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

And the XML looks like

```
 <cam:message xmlns="urn:xxx:1.0:logging">
         <cam:response>
           <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                   <Info xmlns="urn:xxx:1.0:xxx.core.xxx.Service1">
                      <property name="response">some value</property>
                 </Info>
                 <Info xmlns="urn:xxx:1.0:xxx.core.xxx.Service2">
                      <property name="response">i am interested in this value</property>
                 </Info>
               </soapenv:Header>
           </soapenv:Envelope>
     </cam:response>
</cam:message>
```

So the tag `<Info xmlns="urn:xxx:1.0:xxx.core.xxx.Service2">`is having its own name space. My program is not returning value for this. Similarly there are many Info tags. I am interested in the second Info tag that has a namespace ending in Service2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current XPath expression only matches Info and property elements with **no** namespace uri.

You must add the `urn:...Service2`-namespace to you `NamespaceContext` inner class:

```
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
    if ("cam".equals(prefix))
       // like abvce
    else if ("s2".equals(prefix))
       return "urn:xxx:1.0:xxx.core.xxx.Service2";
    else
       return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
}
```

and qualify the `Info` and `property` step in your XPath accordingly, using prefix `s2`:

```
xpath.compile("/cam:message/cam:response/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/s2:Info/s2:property[@name='response']/text()");
```

Beyond that there are errors in your code and the XML file:

a) You make the DocumentBuilderFactory namespace-aware *after* you have created the DocumentBuilder. Write instead:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

b) Your XML uses the prefix `cam` which is not properly declared in the root element. Write instead:

```
<cam:message xmlns:cam="urn:xxx:1.0:logging">
    ....
```

Comment: @wero.i did the changes suggested by you.. Thanks. But I don't see that working either

Comment: @Shiv maybe you have to further tweak your XPath expression.

Comment: i am new to this xpath thing.Although my path looks straightforward and logical to me, clueless as to why it is not working.Any help possible

Comment: @wero.Thank You. Adding the namespace aware before the builder creation fixed the issue.wrt to the changing the xml i don't have control over that. But this change alone fixed my issue.Thank You Agan